# Нужно найти максимум в массиве до первого отрицательного числа. Не пойму, что не так

Tags: python

```
    from random import randint
    n=10
    a=[0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        a[i]=randint(-9, 9)
    print(a)
    otr = 0
    max = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] < 0:
            otr = a[i]
            break
        for i in range(1, n):
            if a[i] > max:
                max = a[i]
    print(max)
    print(otr)
```

Comment: Простите, а вот этот последний блок, который Вы добавили, это что?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы второй цикл неверно ограничили с обеих сторон. Вот он у вас полностью и крутился, а начинался позже. Потестируйте, у меня на десятке прогонов, вроде, нормально. При первом отрицательном максимумом считаю 0, как у вас сделано.

```
from random import randint
n=10
a=[0]*n
for i in range(n):
    a[i]=randint(-9, 9)
print(a)
otr = 0
max = 0
for i in range(n):
    if a[i] < 0:
        otr = a[i]
        break
    # такой range правильнее 
    for i in range(0, i+1):
        print ('i ',i)
        if a[i] > max:
            max = a[i]
print(max)
print(otr)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Анна, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Если что-то осталось нерабочим - напишите тут.

Answer (score 3):

```py
from random import randint
from itertools import takewhile
n = 10
a = [randint(-9, 9) for _ in range(n)]
b = [*takewhile(lambda x: x >= 0, a)]
c = max(b or [None])

negative, *_ = a[len(b):] or [None]

print(f'{a = }')
print(f'{b = }')
print(f'{c = }')
print(f'{negative = }')

# a = [9, 7, 4, -1, 3, 2, -4, 5, -8, 3]
# b = [9, 7, 4]
# c = 9
# negative = -1
```

---

```
# a = [-8, 6, 4, -3, -1, 4, 8, 1, 0, -7]
# b = []
# c = None
# negative = -8
```

> Материалы по теме:
> [takewhile](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-itertools-python/funktsija-takewhile-modulja-itertools/)
> [распаковка](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/prisvaivanie-znachenij-python/prisvaivanie-znachenij-raspakovkoj/)

---

*для любителей однострочников и поборников питоничности*

```py
print(max([*takewhile(lambda x: x >= 0, [randint(-9, 9) for _ in range(10)])] or [None]))
```

Comment: Да, это классно и +1, но учитывая уровень исходного кода, минимальные комментарии были бы полезны Анне:-)

Comment: @Сергей, обратите внимание, на сноску. Помоему так даже лучше будет.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, просто отлично так. И сноска про распаковку сильно лучше той, что я нагуглил.

Comment: @Сергей, там вообще сайт по стандартной либе интересный. Сами пошерстите.

Answer (score 3):

Пришло в голову, что лучше сделать ещё второй вариант. В первом варианте будет ошибка при всех положительных числах, кроме того сам вариант с двумя циклами, где переиспользуется `i` выглядит чрезмерно сложным. Добавил комментарии также.

```
from random import randint
n=10
# Так более "питонически" создавать заполненный список списковым включением
a=[randint(-9,9) for i in range(n)]
print(a)
# Лучше не использовать имя функции языка (max) в качестве переменной  
maximum = 0
# Не пограничный случай: первое число не отрицательное, но отрицательные есть 
if a[0]>=0 and min(a)<0:
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i]<0:
            maximum = max(a[:i])
            break
# Пограничный случай: отрицательных нет            
elif min(a)>=0:
    maximum = max(a)
# Пограничный случай с первым числом отрицательным не нужен, т.к. maximum = 0 сразу
print(maximum)
```

Comment: Я бы добавил этот вариант в первый принятый ответ. Логически отделить от первого варианта его можно при помощи "---" между строками текста ответа

Comment: Не хочу править Ваш код, видно, что Вы дейсвительно постарались, но если уж речь зашла за "питоничность" то вроде как "не комильфо" присваивать имена неиспользуемым переменным. Я бы написал вот так `[randint(-9, 9) for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Спасибо, думал об этом, но не был уверен, что Анна его так заметит. Идёт сообщение автору вопроса, если обновить принятый ответ?

Comment: Нет, но можно добавить под ним коментарий с указанием имени автора Вот так, @Сергей то она получит оповещение, или написать коментарий под вопросом

Comment: @Namerek, да, спасибо большое, я это у вас уже изучил:-) Как и `takewhile` (долго думал, как бы так изловчиться, но не додумался - не знал библиотеку). Просто не стал "стягивать" к себе этот `_`, у Анны есть возможность теперь сравнить неоптимальный, средненький и отличный варианты кода.

Comment: @Сергей, кстати, всегда оставляю разъяснения к коду, кода эти разъяснения не сводятся к переписыванию доков по либе

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо. Тут уже оставлю, как есть 2 варианта, так как ещё и комментарии тут есть, на будущее буду знать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136227/discussion-between--and-namerek).

Comment: import random
import math 
n=6
a=[0]*n
f = [0]*n
for i in range(n):
    for i in range(n):
        a[i]=random.uniform(0, 9)
    for i in range(n):
            for i in range(n):
                f[i] = a[i] - int(a[i])
            for i in range(n-1):
                for j in range(n-i-1):
                    if f[j] > f[j+1]:
                        f[j], f[j+1] = f[j+1], f[j]
print(a)
print(f) Можете, пожалуйста, еще с этим помочь? Программа для вывода чисел в порядке их близости к целым. Решила отделить целую часть и сравнивать дроби. Не получается, вернуть целую обратно

Comment: Можно ли присвоить индексу одного элемента массива элемент из другого массива?

Comment: Анна, 1) не смешивайте разные вопросы, это противоречит правилам форума и логике - открывайте отдельную задачу. 2) Не пишите код Python в комментариях, отступы погибают. Это же не С.

Comment: Анна, индексу присвоить элемент массива, конечно, можно (в Python почти всё можно), но выглядит это подозрительно. Это какой-то массив индексов должен быть. Перемещайтесь в другой вопрос:-)

Comment: Вопросы кончились( я код добавила в этот вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136229/discussion-between-anna-and-).

Answer (score 0):

```
num = [randint(-9,9) for i in range(10)]
for i in num:
    if i < 0:
        ind = num.index(i)
        break
if ind == 0:
    print(0)
else:
    print(max(num[:ind]))
```

А что вам мешает сделать так?

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что я забыл дописать break, а эту ошибку когда нет отрицательных чисел легко убрать, но условиями задачи подобные случаи не описаны и все же мое решение лучше чем банальный поход с присвоениями и последующими переприсвоениями

Comment: Основная проблема - в задиристом стиле общения, не очень принятом на SO:-) А догадаться, что случайный подбор чисел может выдать и всё положительное тоже можно, это входит в условие по умолчанию.

Comment: Кроме того, вариант @Namerek для вывода максимума вообще всего в 3 строки укладывается, ваша конструкция - в 9 строк. Что вы там у него банального нашли - уж не знаю:-)

Comment: @Сергей, на самом деле, тот код записывается в одну строку если отбросить импорт и рюшечки созданные для наглядности. Выглядит это так. `print(max([*takewhile(lambda x: x >= 0, [randint(-9, 9) for _ in range(10)])] or [None]))`